# First order nonhomogeneous non linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation:

$$ y' = \frac{1}{xy+x^2y^3}$$

As far as I understand, this should be the Bernoulli equation (since in all other tasks I solved for different versions of individual homework, this kind of equation was Bernoulli's one).

P.S. Due to typo there was no stroke over $y$, I just assumed that it should be there (although I've tried to change and added it to other $y$ to check results, but various online calculators give out some kind of garbage). The teacher still hasn't answered. I tried to replace $y = uv$, but this doesn't work too.

Please, help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Hm... Thank you, I didn't guess about it.